# IBM Informix Database Encoding Issue With .Net when Retrieve Arabic String

Tags: .net, encoding, arabic, informix

I have faced this issue When retrieve Data From IBM INFORMIX DATABASE

-I have setup Version 2.90 
Data stored in DB like this

> نيمبالى   بادرها  سرادهى  راجو

when i retrieve this from informix get in wrong format like this

> äíãÈÇáì ÈÇÏÑåÇ ÓÑÇÏåì ÑÇÌæ

database used this encoding `en_us.819`
So I have Tried A lot Of Solutions to fix this encoding 
i have create this method in .NET to Uni coding this wrong format to correct Arabic format

```
private static string UniCode_IBM819(string str)
        {
            Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            Encoding unicode =    Encoding.GetEncoding(708);//Encoding.GetEncoding(864);//Encoding.UTF8;
            //byte[] unicodeBytes = unicode.GetBytes(str);
            byte[] isoBytes = iso.GetBytes(str);
            byte[] utfBytes = Encoding.Convert(iso,unicode,  isoBytes);
            return unicode.GetString(utfBytes);


        }
```

i have tried 3 encoding but get me result like

> ?????? ???? ????? ?????

Comment: Try `Windows-1256` encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ISSUE SOLVED

I'm using this method:

```
 private static string UniCodeIso819Towin1256(string src)
        {
            Encoding iso819 = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso8859-1");
            Encoding win1256 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);
            byte[] isoBytes = iso819.GetBytes(src);
            return win1256.GetString(isoBytes);
        }
```

to convert this returned value  'äíãÈÇáì ÈÇÏÑåÇ ÓÑÇÏåì ÑÇÌæ' to the original format like this 'نيمبالى بادرها سرادهى راجو'

Comment: this Link help me to conversion between encoding strings **https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding(v=vs.110).aspx**